Why can't you face nail/screw trusses?
All of the roof trusses I've ever seen use metal truss plates or plywood gussets. Is this fastening method much stronger than just overlapping the boards and face nailing them together? If so, why?

I think with plates/gussets you have wood holding wood.  With face nails/screws you only have the nails/screws holding.  Pushing down a nail does not take much force, pushing a piece of wood down which is on wood, takes a lot of force, two or three foot diameter tree falling on it force.

This might also be a byproduct of manufacturing and transportation requirements. If you doubled the volume of a bundle of trusses, costs would add up.
